# What pannier rack for Cube Cross Race?

Tags: cyclocross, panniers

I am trying to find a suitable pannier rack for my [Cube Cross Race](https://www.cube.eu/2019/bikes/road/road-cyclocross/cross-race/cube-cross-race-blacknred-2019/), but due to weirdly placed eyelets I can't find any.

Can you recommend any that would fit?

Comment: You say the eyelets are strangely placed, but I don't see any at all.

Comment: On the backside of where a cantilever brake would go, and one on the upper tube of the rear triangle (opposite side of the tube where the disk brake is mounted)

Comment: Please add a photo showing how the eyelets are weirdly placed.  Note we don't do specific product recommendations.

Comment: @AronC Criggie is right - even if the answer to your question is "there is none", others with similar bikes might profit from a picture of the eyelets if they come across this question.

Comment: Thank you @anderas . I will upload some photos in the following days.

Comment: The question would really benefit from the photos. The answer says something about eyelets, but we can't see what kind of eyelets are they.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The eyelets on this bike are not made for pannier racks. Their intended use is to mount fenders, so they are probably not built to withstand the loads of a full rack. So unfortunately I suspect that the answer to your question is: "there is none". 
But you can go with bikepacking-style seatpost bags if they fit your use-case (which is what I do).

Source: I own almost the same bike (different model year and higher-level components, but same frame).

Comment: As an aside: The *Cross Race* series is Cube's more race-oriented family of drop-bar offroad bikes. *Nuroad* are more touring-oriented and do have rack mounts.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: Won’t work** for your bike. As Paul and Andreas pointed out in the comments your bike has thru-axles and not QR axles.

---

Tubus offers an adapter for Quick Release axles. Since you have a mounting hole in the seat stay bridge you could use a rack like the Tubus Fly Classic. I’m not sure if the QR adapter is compatible with non-Tubus rear racks.

https://www.tubus.com/en/products/accessories-rear-carriers/tubus-product/adapter-set-for-qr-axle-mounting-rear-carrier/

[image]

Trek also offers a rack complete with adapters: https://www.trekbikes.com/gb/en_GB/equipment/cycling-accessories/bike-racks-mudguards-locks/bike-racks/bontrager-backrack-lightweight/p/08214/

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP has thru-axles, not QR axles

Comment: @PaulH is right - the bike has X12 thru-axles, so this adapter would not work.

Comment: Oh, I only looked at the picture and thought I saw a QR skewer nut. Thanks for pointing it out. I’ve edited the answer but I’ll leave it in case somebody with QR axles stumbles over this thread.

Comment: @Michael Good move. This has definite potential to be a useful answer to somebody.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.
Is there some weird adapter/combo thing from thru axles to QR axles?